# mysql source command do nothing inside docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker

## Description

I'm running docker container with mysql in it and I want to run python script after mysql started, which will apply dump on it.

Here is a snippet of **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python

ADD apply_dump.py /usr/local/bin/apply_dump.py
ADD starter.sh /usr/local/bin/starter.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/starter.sh"]
```

**starter.sh**:

```
nohup python '/usr/local/bin/apply_dump.py' &
mysqld
```

**apply_dump.py**:

```
import os
import urllib
import gzip
import shutil
import subprocess
import time
import logging
import sys

# wait for mysql server
time.sleep(5)
print "Start dumping"

dumpName = "ggg.sql"
dumpGzFile = dumpName + ".gz"
dumpSqlFile = dumpName + ".sql"

print "Loading dump {}...".format(dumpGzFile)
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://ftpUser:ftpPassword@ftpHost/' + dumpGzFile, '/tmp/' + dumpGzFile)

print "Extracting dump..."
with gzip.open('/tmp/' + dumpGzFile, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('/tmp/' + dumpSqlFile, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

        print "Dropping database..."
        subprocess.call(["mysql", "-u", "root", "-proot", "-e", "drop database if exists test_db"])

        print "Creating database..."
        subprocess.call(["mysql", "-u", "root", "-proot", "-e", "create schema test_db"])

        print "Applying dump..."
        subprocess.call(["mysql", "--user=root", "--password=root", "test_db", "-e" "source /tmp/{}".format(dumpSqlFile)])
        print "Done"
```

content of **ggg.sql.gz** is pretty simple:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

### Problem

Database created, but table is not. If I'll go to container and will run this script manually, table will be created. If I'll replace `source` command with direct sql create statement that will work as well. But in reality dump file will be pretty big and only `source` command will cope with this (or not only it?). Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the issue is in your starter.sh script. You're running your python script that inserts data to MySQL before the MySQL service has been started. I'd guess that the `subprocess.call()` calls are actually failing. Have you checked their return values (exit codes). Anything other than a zero will indicate that the mysql binary you're calling returned a failure. The database is created as part of the MySQL docker image spinning up, which is probably why that exists even though the table doesn't.

Comment: I believe it is not the case, because schema drop and create are working correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your source SQL file into the MySQL command like this, instead of using the `-e` flag:

```
subprocess.call(["mysql", "--user=root", "--password=root", "test_db", "<", "/tmp/%s" % dumpSqlFile])
```

This will call import your SQL file using the widely used syntax:

`mysql --user=root --password=root test_db < /tmp/source.sql`

Comment: In that case I'm getting help message from mysql like this https://gist.github.com/skrauchenia/e747efc3626c3cb5e6f6be6cee263b4b

Comment: See my revised python code. It was most likely failing due to the `subprocess.call()` method escaping the `<` symbol.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Did you tried to execute this code? Did it works?